# Is there a way to test when the hour is perfect like 1:00, 2:00, 3:00 vs 1:15, 2:15, and 3:15 in SQL?

Tags: sql

I want to report the column 'Start' as 1PM when it's 1:00PM, or to report it as 1:15PM when it's 1:15PM.

```
[Start] = Case When Right(Convert(varchar,c.CourseStartTime), 5) = '00:00'
Then Format(Cast(c.CourseStartTime As Datetime), 'htt') 
Else Format(Cast(c.CourseStartTime As Datetime), 'h:mmtt')End,
[End] = Case When Right(Convert(varchar,c.CourseEndTime), 5) = '00:00'
Then Format(Cast(c.CourseEndTime As Datetime), 'htt') 
Else Format(Cast(c.CourseEndTime As Datetime), 'h:mmtt')End,
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  The answer to this question is highly dependent on the database.

Comment: What do you want to report if it's 1:11 for example?

Comment: Your code is not (standard) "SQL" to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax suggests SQL Server.  I think `replace()` with `format()` does what you want:

```
select replace(format(getdate(), 'h:mmtt'), ':00', '')
```